# keydown does not capture 'DEL' key over canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events

I need to handle deletion of nodes from Canvas by pressing the <kbd>Del</kbd> button. 
So, what I'm doing is:

```
const canvasDiv = document.getElementById('main_diagram')
canvasDiv.childNodes[0].tabIndex = '1'
```

I'm setting `tabIndex` of canvas element to 1 (dirty old trick to make any element focusable) and than just adding `eventListener`:

```
canvasDiv.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    console.log(e.keyCode)
}, false)
```

Code above is not working for <kbd>Delete</kbd> button, however, when I change listener to **keyup** - it does.

I didn't find any explanation on why these two events behave so differently, that they wont capture same keys. Can anybody shed some light on it?

(This is using Chrome on Windows 10)

Comment: Which browser and OS? Can't repro on my mac, neither on FF nor on Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/wtegchvk/

Comment: @Kaiido - good question, chrome on  win10